# Why am I getting Run-time error '1004' with my VBA code to copy and paste from one workbook to another?

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste, doevents, selectmethod

I am having trouble with my VBA code for my macro that I want to open the msoFileDialogFolderPicker and the user pick a folder in which all the excel files will be opened and one by one data will be copied from the newly open workbook and pasted into specific sheets in the workbook where the macro is running. Basically we give each of our sales rep a spreadsheet to fill out of their sales and then they submit their spreadsheets to the sales manager. What I want to do instead of someone having to open up each spreadsheet and copy the data and paste all of it into one spreadsheet manually, is to simply have a macro that does this for me. Since the location and names of the files can change, I am trying to make it as dynamic as possible. There may be a better way of doing this, so any suggestions are much appreciated!

The issue I am having is that I get the files to open and they copy, but then I get a Run Time Error 1004 'Copy method of Range Class Failed' when I try to get it to paste in the workbook that is running the macro. I have tried ThisWorkbook and ThisWorkbook.Activate to try and tell Excel to go to the spreadsheet where the macro is running, but none solved my problem. Sometimes I get past the error but it still never pastes the data in the master workbook. I have my code written below. Admittedly, it has been mostly copied from code I have found but I have tried to adapt it for my purpose. The line I am getting the error on is the "wb1.Worksheets(1).Range("A5").Select" line.

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim myPath As String
    Dim myFile As String
    Dim myExtension As String
    Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

  With FldrPicker
    .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
      If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
      myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
  End With


NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

myExtension = "*.xls*"

myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

Do While myFile <> ""
  Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
  Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook

  Do events

  wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A5:H28").Select
Selection.Copy
  wb1.Activate
  wb1.Worksheets(1).Range("A5").Select
  ActiveSheet.Paste

  DoEvents

  myFile = Dir
Loop

  MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:

  Application.EnableEvents = True
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

This is a simplified version of what I am eventually going to do, which includes copying things from multiple worksheets in the newly opened workbook and pasting them in multiple sheets of the originally macro-running workbook. At this point however, I am just trying to get this simple version to run and work. Thank you all for all your help and my apologies for the long code, but I want to give everyone an idea of exactly what I am doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stop using `Select` and `Activate` and writing code that uses `Selection` - that's for the macro recorder. You're not a macro recorder, you can write much better code than that.

This is doing too many things and trapping you with late-bound calls working off `Object`, which means you're typing code blindly without any help from *IntelliSense*, no autocompletion, no tooltips:

```
wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A5:H28").Select
```

You want a `Range` object here.

```
Dim source As Range
Set source = wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A5:H28")
```

Now, when you type `source.`, *IntelliSense* can help you. Go on, try:

```
source.Copy[space]
```

Notice the tooltip telling you that you can specify a destination right there and then.

So make another range:

```
Dim destination As Range
Set destination = wb1.Worksheets(1).Range("A5")
```

And copy away!

```
source.Copy destination
```

Now, you should probably call `wb.Close` before the end of that loop...

Comment: Okay thanks. I think I am getting it to work, but planning on tackling it again tomorrow so I want to keep the thread open to make sure. Also, any idea on how to make this work to copy and paste in the loop, but not write/paste over the existing data? Basically all the data goes in one table and one be pasted one under the other. Some workbooks that are open in the msofolderpicker will have 90 entries, while some could have only 50. No way to have an exact number, so I need to keep it dynamic in that sense.